# Set div width from a function

Tags: jquery, css

i need to set the width of a div container to be 100% - 150px

How can this be achived using jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#yourdiv').width( $('#yourdiv').width() - 150 )
```

Also have a look at the [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  $("#id").width('100%');
  var width = $("#id").width();
  $("#id").width(width - 150);
```

JQuery documentation: 
http://api.jquery.com/width/

Answer (score 0):

If you're basing it on the window you can use:

```
var width = $(window).width() - 150;
$("#container").css("width", width);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div = $('div');
parent_width = div.parent().width();
div.width(parent_width - 150);
```